# Does $L^2(M)$ always admit a basis of nowhere-vanishing functions?

Tags: manifolds, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

Let $M$ be compact manifold without boundary equipped with a smooth measure. Since continuous complex-valued functions are dense in $L^2(M)$, the Gramm-Schmidt process shows that $L^2(M)$ admits an orthonormal basis $(e_n)$ of continuous functions.

> **Question:** Is it always possible to find $(e_n)$ as above so that each $e_n$ is nowhere-vanishing? If not, what obstructs us from doing this?

- If $M=G$ is a compact abelian Lie group with Haar measure, then this is possible since we may use the dual group $\widehat G$ as a basis. These are not only nowhere-vanishing, but actually circle-valued.
- If $M=S^2$, I suspect things don't work out. As with any Riemann manifold, we can consider the eigenfunctions of the Laplacian to get a basis of nice smooth functions. For $S^2$, these are the spherical harmonics. However, eigenspaces here have common zeros, apparently. One can learn more by googling "nodal sets".

Comment: Maybe this is obvious, but if you want a real-valued ONB, this is not possible if $M $ is connected: Indeed, if $f : M \to \Bbb {R} $ does not vanish, then $f>0$ or $f <0$. But two such functions cannot satisfy $\langle f,g \rangle =0$. Hence, we must look at complex-valued bases.

Comment: @PhoemueX: Yes I want to work over the complex numbers (there is a slightly buried reference to this in the first paragraph of the post). However, thanks all the same for pointing out that complex scalars are necessary!